# Looping issue when rendering an object hierarchy using Dust.JS 2.7.2 to ul/li tags

Tags: dust.js

I'm trying to render an object structure in Dust 2.7.2 such as

```
{
   name:"Home Page",
   url: "/",
   "sub-page1": {
        name: "Sub Page 1",
        url: "/sub-page1",
        "sub-sub-page1": {
             "name": "Sub Sub Page1",
             "url": "/sub-page1/sub-sub-page1"
        }
    }
}
```

to something like

```html
<ul><li><a href="/">Home Page</a><ul><li><a href="/subpage1">Sub Page 1</a> ...
```

with a recursive partial, but I can't seem to loop through the variably named objects without causing an infinite loop.
My current attempt looks like this, with the partial calling itself:

```html
<li>
    <a href="{url}">{name}</a>{#.}<ul>{>"components/menu/recurlist"/}</ul>{/.}
</li>
```

Comment: I'll put up a more complete solution when I get to a computer, but `{#.}` will always evaluate its contents. Dust won't be able to handle this recursively because your subpage keys have different names. The structure of each level should look the same.

Comment: Ok thank you that would be really helpful! Yes it's done this way so the tree can be traversed quickly by JS using the key names to resolve a URL.  I want to invert this to render the menu as well using Dust.  I've written a recursive JS function in the past to do it, but now want to use native Dust as it's more flexible formatting wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way for Dust to guess the name of your nested context object when it changes every time. You really need to keep the nesting structure identical at all levels. If you absolutely must, you can write custom helpers to get around that, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Once you have normalized data, your template becomes simple:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="{url}">{name}</a>
    {#subpage}{>"components/menu/recurlist"/}{/subpage}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it further.  I have worked around it with JS code re-processing the data before rendering.